Deployed Django project on vercel can't see tables on the database
I have deployed a django project through vercel and my log in and sign up authentication can't seem to go through. The error shows that the table where I store my users, are not visible to the vercel deployed app. But when I try the project locally, the project works fine with no errors in the log in sign up. Here's the error deployed project error Message.  Here's the Github Repository as well.
I tried re-configuring my django project to make it vercel ready and also tried to change database host (I am using postgreSQL initially from Railway to Supabase)

Run migrate on the production database.

Please don't refer to a GitHub repository only. Include all the necessary technical details in the question: the GitHub repository might eventually dissapear rendering the question useless. Furthermore you can not expect people to browse through an entire project.

If using a PostgreSQL database provided by railway.app, Click on Provision PostgreSQL, go to variables and get the credentials for your database. Enter those credentials into the DATABASES of your settings.py file. Then run
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

Now all the tables of your database will be shown in the railway database.
If on Supabase, create a new project, go to Databases, get your database credentials and enter into the DATABASES of your settings.py file. Then run
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

See Deploying Django apps on Vercel
